# How to apply if condition on multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum cells that meet certain criteria in another cells. The image below shows an illustration of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

If I follow the approach shown in the image above to sum all the W's, this requires an IF statement for each W which is inconvenient because I have a dataset that goes from W1 to W100. Is there an efficient way to get the conditional sum when in case I have multiple W's without writing IF statement for all cells? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `=SUMIF(F10:J10,"<" & G6,F9:J9)`

Comment: Its super Scott to the rescue with a speedy response up his sleeve!

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula, copy this into a cell and press cntrl+shift+enter

```
=sumproduct(F9:CZ9,if(F10:CZ10<G6,1,0))
```

This checks if cells f10 to cz10 are less than g6 and creates an array with values of 0 (if >=g6) and 1 (

Comment: drop the IF and you dont need to make it a CSE.  Just use `=sumproduct($F$9:$CZ$9*($F$10:$CZ$10<$G$6))